# Get a user's time zone with Get User Profile V2 in a Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Get user profile (V2) doesn't return a time zone as part of the default data returned.

I also tried to select mailboxSettings or timeZone (part of mailboxSettings), but I'm not getting data back.

mailboxSettings returned ErrorAccessDenied.

timeZone returned:
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(timeZone)/$entity"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you could get the timezone cause the action `Get user profile (V2)` response body `GraphUser_V1` doesn't contain the timezone property. You could check the connector details:[GraphUser_V1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365users/#graphuser_v1).

So you could only add the path filter it provides like aboutMe,accountEnabled etc, it's the Path property in the `GraphUser_V1`.

As for the timezone you want I think the Office 365 API could help you, you could use this API in the logic app: [Get user mailbox settings API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#response-type-15).

Comment: Thanks! The documentation also says this though for Get user profile (V2): Retrieves the profile of a specific user. Learn more about available fields to select: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user#properties. That's where I found mailboxSettings and timeZone. Maybe I'll open a support ticket.

Comment: @Jonathan M,yes the REST api did provide the mailboxSettings  property to get, so I suggest you could use the REST api to get the property. As for Get user profile (V2), cause the response body doesn't include the property so may be you could ask for the [azure support feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: @Jonathan M, and if this could help you, you could mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions, but I was trying to use the built-in action. It looks like a permission issue. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3289

Comment: @Jonathan M, it's a different problem. He is trying use the REST api and you are using the logic app actions.